# jquery datepicker control is not working properly in my localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to develope a javascript code for calender i tried in my jsfiddle which work good but only in jsfiddle i want to develope it in JavaScript and also there is one problem that it not displaying next and previous button in my local site you can check jsfiddle below and also check snapshot of my localsite

here is my jquery code
 please go through it and give me suggetions to solve this

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  }
  );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FFbyS/  jsfiddle

http://screencast.com/t/mTSAJmU55D  screenshot
please help

Comment: you have to load jquery UI CSS and images and JS files

Answer (score 0):

first include jQuery File

then Include jqueryUi related  file  then it will work

like below reference **[datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and i already uploaded it but still not working so need your help to develope in pure js can you help me??

Comment: jquery datepicker control is not displaying "next" and "previous" icons at top

Answer (score 0):

Chk this code,you have to load jquery UI CSS and images and JS files

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/base2.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker();
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="Datepicker" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery datepicker control is not displaying "next" and "previous" icons at top